# UITableView multiple cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4

I make Iphone application and I want make my table view to look like home screen. I mean to make grid  4x4. I want to can touch either button from row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple columns in a uitableview, one way to accomplish what you want is to use a scrollview and place each view in it with the appropriate frames in order to make it look as you wish, another way might be to add the views as you wnt them to the cells however I think the first option gives you more flexibility

Hope this helps

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

A table view is not going to work for something like this. The easiest route would be to use Three20's `TTLauncherView`, which mimics much of the functionality of the iOS Home Screen.

Three20 source: https://github.com/facebook/three20

TTLauncherView tutorial: http://iosguy.com/2010/10/19/tthree20-a-brief-ttlauncherview-tutorial/